# How can i give padding to Sfslider trackShape in flutter?

Tags: flutter, slider, syncfusion

The dividers in my track shape are attached to its corners/endings ([see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APWQA.png)).

I want them to be a little apart and space. How can I give padding to Sfslider trackShape?

my code is:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SfSliderTheme(
            data: SfSliderThemeData(
              tickOffset: const Offset(0, 0),
              activeTrackHeight: 15,
              inactiveTrackHeight: 15,
              thumbRadius: 8,
              activeTrackColor: Colors.pink,
              inactiveTrackColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
              activeDividerColor: Colors.white,
              inactiveDividerColor: Colors.white,
              thumbColor: const Color(0xff39b5ed),
              tooltipBackgroundColor: const Color(0xff39b5ed),
              tooltipTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              activeDividerRadius: 3.5,
              inactiveDividerRadius: 3.5,
            ),
            child: SfSlider(
              tooltipShape: const SfRectangularTooltipShape(),
              min: 1.0,
              max: 5.0,
              value: _value,
              interval: 1,
              showDividers: true,
              // showTicks: true,
              showLabels: true,
              shouldAlwaysShowTooltip: true,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _value = value;
                });},),),],),);}}
```

I searched everywhere and could not find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no direct support for adding padding to the divider in the slider. However, we have fulfilled your requirement by extending the [SfDividerShape](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_sliders/latest/sliders/SfDividerShape-class.html) class and rendering the custom divider shape. We then assign it to the [dividerShape](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_sliders/latest/sliders/SfSlider/dividerShape.html) property in the [SfSlider](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_sliders/latest/sliders/SfSlider-class.html). We have prepared a sample and shared its code snippet below for your reference.

**Code snippet:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_sliders/sliders.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_core/theme.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MyHomePageState();
  double _value = 3.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SfSliderTheme(
            data: SfSliderThemeData(
              activeTrackHeight: 15,
              inactiveTrackHeight: 15,
              activeTrackColor: Colors.pink,
              inactiveTrackColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
              thumbColor: const Color(0xff39b5ed),
              tooltipBackgroundColor: const Color(0xff39b5ed),
              tooltipTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            child: SfSlider(
              tooltipShape: const SfRectangularTooltipShape(),
              min: 1.0,
              max: 5.0,
              value: _value,
              interval: 1,
              showDividers: true,
              showLabels: true,
              dividerShape: _DividerShape(),
              shouldAlwaysShowTooltip: true,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _value = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _DividerShape extends SfDividerShape {
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center, Offset? thumbCenter,
      Offset? startThumbCenter, Offset? endThumbCenter,
      {required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SfSliderThemeData themeData,
      SfRangeValues? currentValues,
      dynamic currentValue,
      required Paint? paint,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required TextDirection textDirection}) {
    bool isActive;

    switch (textDirection) {
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        isActive = center.dx <= thumbCenter!.dx;
        break;
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        isActive = center.dx >= thumbCenter!.dx;
        break;
    }

    context.canvas.drawCircle(
        center,
        // Divider radius
        6,
        Paint()
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
          ..color = Colors.white);
    context.canvas.drawCircle(
        center,
        // Divider stroke radius
        6,
        Paint()
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 3.5
          ..color = isActive ? Colors.pink : Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3));
  }
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]